# Spring Namespace Error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am continually getting the following error during testing:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
```

It is originating from my persistenceLayer.xml file. Here is it's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="persistenceManager" class="com.apollo.counterpartcontacts.service.PersistenceManager">
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config /> 

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="CounterpartContactDataSource" /> 
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="CounterpartContacts" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Also, here is my application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- 
        This file can be included into other file which already has PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers. 
        Spring requires different syntax for them. 
        For scanning the properties from this PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, use @[]. Make sure 
        other set of configuration files not use @[] to scan properties.
    -->
    <bean id="credentialConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="@["/>
        <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="]"/>

        <property name="location" value="file:c:/ACM/private/credentials.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="persistenceLayer.xml" />

    <bean id="CounterpartContactDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="${CounterpartContact.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="@[mdMsSqlCounterpartContact_Login=login]"/>
        <property name="password" value="@[mdMsSqlCounterpartContact_Password=password]"/>
        <property name="defaultCatalog" value="${CounterpartContact.Catalog}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Additionally, here is a list of all my .jar files:

```
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\ant-contrib-0.6.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\antlr.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\aopalliance.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\asm-attrs.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\asm.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\aspectjrt.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\aspectjweaver.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\cfgatewayadapter.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\clear-runtime-blazeds.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\clear-runtime-core.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\clear.cdb.annotations.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\com.farata.dto2fx.annotations.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.6.1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\concurrent.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\connector-1_5.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\flex-messaging-common.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\flex-messaging-core.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\flex-messaging-opt.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\flex-messaging-proxy.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\flex-messaging-remoting.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\flex-rds-server.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate3.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\howl.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jotm.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jotm_iiop_stubs.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jotm_jrmp_stubs.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jta-1.1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jta-spec1_0_1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jts1_0.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\objectweb-datasource.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.flex.roo.addon-1.0.0.M1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.flex.roo.annotations-1.0.0.M1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\ow_carol.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\serializer.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-flex-core-1.5.0.M2.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-acl-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-cas-client-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-ldap-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-openid-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\sqljdbc-3.0.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\testng-6.1.1.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\xalan.jar
C:\dev\grailsflex\CounterpartContacts\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\xapool.jar
```

And here is the classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.6.0_26">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="flex_src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/sqljdbc_3.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to use the Spring 2.5 namespace declarations with the Spring 3.0.5 JARs. Use one or the other; don't mix.

For the record, I use this sort of thing in my code (with 3.0.5-RELEASE JARs, so it should be comparable to your situation) and it works for me:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: Good point, I had this kind of version conflict in the past giving me hell lot of unnecessary challenges which are kind of not straight forward to figure out.

Comment: Although this makes a lot of sense, it did not resolve the error. Still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?52256-Unable-to-locate-NamespaceHandler-for-namespace-..-context

Comment: I looked at that earlier. The thing is that I have the latest version of Spring, so I don't know if that really applies to me.